# Is there a simple way to utilize Prestashop's login functionality?

Tags: php, web-services, session, cookies, prestashop

I was looking through the docs for Prestashop's web service API and it's great for retrieving data.

I planned on creating a page which would display various data via the web service but I wish to protect the page from the public.

Is there a way I can easily include the administrative login functionality to my page?

Comment: Why don't you enable maintenance mode and add your ip to the whitelist?

Comment: @joseantgv My store is a public store, I only need to block access to one specific page

Comment: @Ashely Brown Understood!

Answer (score 0):

You can use web server basic authorization.

(nginx): http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

(apache): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html